# How to expose AdWords to JavaScript via ClearScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-ads-api, jscript, clearscript

Context: VS2015 Community; C#; ClearScript.V8.5.4.5; Google.AdWords.18.25.0

I'm trying to create a scripting environment to do my Budgets. One the C# side, I'm setting up a JScript environment, and exposing all the AdWords types and objects that I need to it, viz

```
    static JScriptEngine JSengine = null;
    static Dictionary<string, object> Settings = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("engine script.js");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        string scriptSpec = args[0];

        try
        {
            JSengine = new JScriptEngine(WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableDebugging | WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableJITDebugging);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return;
        }

        // .. others as well e.g. File, Environment etc

        JSengine.AddHostType("AdWordsUser", typeof(AdWordsUser));
        JSengine.AddHostType("AdWordsAppConfig", typeof(AdWordsAppConfig));
        JSengine.AddHostType("BudgetOrderService", typeof(BudgetOrderService));
        JSengine.AddHostType("Selector", typeof(Selector));
        JSengine.AddHostType("Predicate", typeof(Predicate));
        JSengine.AddHostType("BudgetOrderPage", typeof(BudgetOrderPage));
        JSengine.AddHostType("BudgetOrder", typeof(BudgetOrder));
        JSengine.AddHostType("PredicateOperator", typeof(PredicateOperator));
        JSengine.AddHostType("AdWordsService", typeof(AdWordsService));

        JSengine.AddHostObject("Settings", Settings);

        object answer = null;
        string script = File.ReadAllText(scriptSpec);
        try
        {
            answer = JSengine.Evaluate(script);
        }
        catch (ScriptEngineException see)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(see.ErrorDetails);
        }
    }
```

I've done this kind of thing a few times already, so no surprises there.

The difficulty I'm having at the moment is one the JScript side. The code at this point looks like this:

```
var user = new AdWordsUser();
user.OAuthProvider.ClientId = "anonymised.apps.googleusercontent.com";
user.OAuthProvider.ClientSecret = "anonymised";
user.OAuthProvider.AccessToken = "";
user.Config.OAuth2RefreshToken = "anonymised";
user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken();

var config = new AdWordsAppConfig();
config.ClientCustomerId = "anonymised";
config.DeveloperToken = "anonymised";
config.UserAgent = "anonymised";
config.OAuth2ClientId = user.OAuthProvider.ClientId;
config.OAuth2ClientSecret = user.OAuthProvider.ClientSecret;
config.OAuth2AccessToken = user.OAuthProvider.AccessToken;
config.OAuth2RefreshToken = user.Config.OAuth2RefreshToken;

var bos = user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201603.BudgetOrderService);
var bas = bos.getBillingAccounts();
```

At this point, `bos` knows nothing about `getBillingAccounts`. The only way for `bos` to know about it is to execute

```
var bos = new BudgetOrderService();
```

However, then there's no connection then between `bos` and the values it needs in `user`, and attempting to execute `getBillingAccounts` raises an error.

The original C# code from which this derives is

```
BudgetOrderService bos = (BudgetOrderService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201603.BudgetOrderService);
BillingAccount[] bas = bos.getBillingAccounts();
```

Casting the `GetService` call to `BudgetOrderService` seems to be sufficient to make `getBillingAccounts` visible in `bos`. However, JScript doesn't let me do that.

So where to from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the cast in script code. Try this:

```
// C#
JSengine.Script.host = new HostFunctions();
```

Then, in your script:

```
// JavaScript
var bos = user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201603.BudgetOrderService);
bos = host.cast(BudgetOrderService, bos);
```

Or you can expose a delegate that does the cast in C# code.

Comment: Brilliant! I ended up using ExtendedHostFunctions.