# Trapping Adwords errors in JScript when called from ClearScript?

Tags: c#, google-ads-api, jscript, clearscript

Context: VS2015 Community; C#; ClearScript.V8.5.4.5; Google.AdWords.18.25.0

For background on this posting, see an [earlier posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185510/how-to-expose-adwords-to-javascript-via-clearscript) (Kudos, by the way, to @BitCortex for solving the first conundrum.)

I now have a working Adwords mutation scripted in JScript via ClearScript and C#. The challenge now is to handle errors.

In the following chunk of code, I'm creating a new `BudgetOrder`:

```
var order = new BudgetOrder();
order.billingAccountId = acct.id;
order.startDateTime = "20160801 000000 Australia/Perth";
order.endDateTime = "20160831 235959 Australia/Perth";

var amt = new Money();
amt.microAmount = 10000000;
order.spendingLimit = amt;

var boo = new BudgetOrderOperation();
boo.operator = Operator.ADD;
boo.operand = order;
var mutations = ToTypedArray(BudgetOrderOperation, [boo]);

var response;
try {
  response = bos.mutate(mutations);
  Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].billingAccountId);
  Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].id);
  Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].lastRequest.status.ToString());
} catch (exc) {
  Console.WriteLine(exc.message);
}

...

function ToTypedArray(typ, arr) {
  var T;
  if ("string" === typeof typ) {
    T = host.type(typ);
  } else {
    T = typ;
  }
  var a = host.newArr(T, arr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    a.SetValue(arr[i], i);
  }
  return a;
}
```

The problem I'm having at the moment is that if there is an error, `exc` doesn't have anything useful in it apart from

```
exc
{...}
    description: ""
    message: ""
    name: "Error"
    number: -2146190593
```

for example, and `response` is *undefined*.

The usual data that would be available in a `BudgetOrderReturnValue` running natively in C# is not stored anywhere I can see.

I did try casting the result of the mutate using

```
response = host.cast(BudgetOrderReturnValue,bos.mutate(mutations));
```

but when the error occurs, `response` is still set as *undefined*.

I've been able to capture the XML for the mutate having specified

```
<add name="AdsClientLibs.DetailedRequestLogs" value="All" />
```

in `App.config` which gives me a `detailed_logs.log` in `C:\Logs\Adwords`. Thus when an error occurs I've been able to go back to that log and see what the error was, e.g.

```
        <detail>
            <ns2:ApiExceptionFault xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201603" xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/billing/v201603">
                <message>[BudgetOrderError.INVALID_BUDGET_DATE_RANGE @ operations[0].operand.startDateTime.endDateTime; trigger:'Overlapping budget found']</message>
                <ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type>
                <errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:BudgetOrderError">
                    <fieldPath>operations[0].operand.startDateTime.endDateTime</fieldPath>
                    <trigger>Overlapping budget found</trigger>
                    <errorString>BudgetOrderError.INVALID_BUDGET_DATE_RANGE</errorString>
                    <ApiError.Type>BudgetOrderError</ApiError.Type>
                    <ns2:reason>INVALID_BUDGET_DATE_RANGE</ns2:reason>
                </errors>
            </ns2:ApiExceptionFault>
        </detail>
```

However, none of that data seems to be available to the script.

Ideas, anyone?

**LATER**

```
var response;
var hostException;
var succeeded = host.tryCatch(
    function () {
    response = bos.mutate(mutations);
    return true;
  },
    function (exception) {
    hostException = exception;
    return false;
  });
if (succeeded) {
  // process response
  Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].billingAccountId);
  Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].id);
  Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].lastRequest.status.ToString());

} else {
  // handle host exception
  if (host.isType(BudgetOrderError, hostException)) {
    Console.WriteLine("BudgetOrderException");
  } else if (host.isType(ClientTermsError, hostException)) {
    Console.WriteLine("ClientTermsError");
  }
  //...
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The bos.mutate line causes the script to crash with an uncaught error.

**NEXT DAY**

The output from the EXE running the script:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    at JScript global code (Script Document [temp]:149:0) -> var succeeded = host.tryCatch(
    function () {
    response = bos.mutate(mutations);
    return true;
  },
    function (exception) {
    hostException = exception;
    return false;
  })
```

The C# code

```
        string script = File.ReadAllText(scriptSpec);
        try
        {
            answer = JSengine.Evaluate(script);
        }
        catch (ScriptEngineException see)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(see.ErrorDetails);
            ScriptEngineException next = see.InnerException as ScriptEngineException;
            while (next != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(next.ErrorDetails);
                next = next.InnerException as ScriptEngineException;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
```

The JScript code as above. So the ClearScript engine appears not to be doing well with tryCatch.

**A COUPLE OF DAYS LATER**

I've learned one thing at least out of this: I don't need to put

```
WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableDebugging | WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableJITDebugging
```

into my C# code when instantiating the `JScriptEngine` object. If there's a `debugger;` statement in the script, I'll get prompted to start a debugging session.

But back to the script

```
    debugger;

    var CFG = new Config(Path.Combine(Settings.Item("EXEPath"), "mutator2.cfg"));

    var config = new AdWordsAppConfig();
    config.DeveloperToken = CFG.Retrieve("DeveloperToken");
    config.UserAgent = CFG.Retrieve("UserAgent");
    config.ClientCustomerId = CFG.Retrieve("CustomerID");
    config.RetryCount = 10;

    var user = new AdWordsUser(config);
    user.OAuthProvider.ClientId = CFG.Retrieve("ClientId");
    user.OAuthProvider.ClientSecret = CFG.Retrieve("ClientSecret");
    //user.OAuthProvider.AccessToken = CFG.Retrieve("AccessToken");
    user.Config.OAuth2RefreshToken = CFG.Retrieve("OAuth2RefreshToken");
    try {
      user.OAuthProvider.RefreshAccessToken();
    } catch (ex) {
      Console.WriteLine("RefreshAccessToken failed.");
      Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    var bos = user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201603.BudgetOrderService);
    bos = host.cast(BudgetOrderService, bos);

    //bos.RequestHeader.clientCustomerId = config.ClientCustomerId;
    //bos.RequestHeader.developerToken = config.DeveloperToken;
    //bos.RequestHeader.userAgent = config.UserAgent;

    bas = bos.getBillingAccounts();

    var order = new BudgetOrder();
    order.billingAccountId = CFG.Retrieve("BillingID");
    order.startDateTime = "20160801 000000 Australia/Perth";
    order.endDateTime = "20160830 000000 Australia/Perth";

    var amt = new Money();
    amt.microAmount = 10000000;
    order.spendingLimit = amt;

    var boo = new BudgetOrderOperation();
    boo.operator = Operator.ADD;
    boo.operand = order;
    var mutations = ToTypedArray(BudgetOrderOperation, [boo]);
    // bos.RequestHeader.validateOnly = true;

    var response;
    var hostException;

    var succeeded = host.tryCatch(
        function () {
        response = bos.mutate(mutations);
      },
        function (exception) {
        hostException = exception;
        return true;
      });
    if (succeeded) {
      // process response
      Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].billingAccountId);
      Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].id);
      Console.WriteLine(response.value[0].lastRequest.status.ToString());

    } else {
      // handle host exception
      if (host.isType(BudgetOrderError, hostException)) {
        Console.WriteLine("BudgetOrderException");
      } else if (host.isType(ClientTermsError, hostException)) {
        Console.WriteLine("ClientTermsError");
      }
      //...
    }

    function qq(v, d) {
      if (null === v) {
        return "undefined" === typeof d ? "" : d;
      } else {
        return v;
      }
    }

    function ToTypedArray(typ, arr) {
      var T;
      if ("string" === typeof typ) {
        T = host.type(typ);
      } else {
        T = typ;
      }
      var a = host.newArr(T, arr.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        a.SetValue(arr[i], i);
      }
      return a;
    }
```

The first time through, it works fine. The second time through, with the dates unchanged, throws an AdWords error (date range already taken) which causes the JScriptEngine to throw an unhandled exception error. I get prompted to start a debugging session which on launch shows a dialog containing

```
Unhandled exception at line 52, column 2 in JScript - script block
0x8013baff - unknown exception
```

and the highlight on the line `response = bos.mutate(mutations);`. And this happens whether I've got a `debugger;` statement or not.

So I'm giving up on the scripting of AdWords using ClearScript. Maybe I should file this as a bug with the folk at ClearScript.

Comment: Strange. For me the `debugger` statement does nothing unless I enable script debugging via `WindowsScriptEngineFlags`. In any case, if you're seeing that unhandled exception in a script debugger (Visual Studio?), then it's probably OK. The host exception is unhandled from the script engine's point of view, but if you continue execution, the host will catch it and pass it into your handler function. Your handler function returns `true`, telling ClearScript not to rethrow the exception, so no crash will be seen outside the debugger. That's the way it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JScript has limited support for host exception handling, but you could try `HostFunctions.tryCatch`:

```
var hostException;
var succeeded = host.tryCatch(
    function() {
        response = bos.mutate(mutations);
    },
    function(exception) {
        hostException = exception;
        return true;
    }
);
if (succeeded) {
    // process response
    ...
}
else {
    // handle host exception
    if (host.isType(BudgetOrderError, hostException)) { ... }
    else if (host.isType(ClientTermsError, hostException)) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Obviously for this to work you must expose the host exception types (`BudgetOrderError` et al) via `ScriptEngine.AddHostType`.

Comment: I'm giving this the tick because it should work, at least as far as the documentation is concerned. However, it doesn't work. I still get a "Unhandled exception at line 154, column 5 in JScriptEngine/Script Document [temp].js

0x8013baff - unknown exception" error

Comment: ... and the point of crash is `    response = bos.mutate(mutations);`

Comment: Are you seeing a crash outside the debugger? If so, are you sure your handler (the second function passed into `tryCatch`) is returning `true`?

Comment: See "NEXT DAY" addition. I can send you sources but you'll have to have your own AdWords accounts as I'm not free to share mine with you.

Comment: Your JavaScript code passes two functions into `host.tryCatch`. The second one returns `false`, meaning "rethrow exception". It needs to return `true`, meaning "I've handled the exception". Also, a minor point: the return value from the first function (the one that calls `mutate`) is ignored, so there's no need to return it.